# bulk updating in inner array with mongodb and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The below given is my document

```
{
        "_id": 7,
        "sections": [
            {
                "sectionData": {
                    "media": [
                        {
                            "_id": {
                                "$oid": "64a691e0c91b64aa2c0446ce"
                            },
                            "image": "1.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": {
                                "$oid": "64a6922ac91b64aa2c0446d1"
                            },
                            "image": "1.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": {
                                "$oid": "64a69240c91b64aa2c0446d2"
                            },
                            "image": "1.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": {
                                "$oid": "64a6927dc91b64aa2c0446d3"
                            },
                            "image": "1.jpg"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "648847b944e80a387f627028"
                }
            },
            {
                "sectionData": {
                    "media": []
                },
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "648aa5442b511184130685c7"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I wanted to update a field inside media array by matching _id in the objects.

i will recieve a array of ids and values like this

```
let ids = [
  { _id: "64a691e0c91b64aa2c0446ce", eligible: false },
  { _id: "64a6922ac91b64aa2c0446d1", eligible: false },
  { _id: "64a69240c91b64aa2c0446d2", eligible: true },
];
```

I wanted to match the _id in the object and update the eligible value respectively.

here is my code,

```
   const albumId = 7;
    const sectionId = "648847b944e80a387f627028";
    let ids = [
      { _id: "64a691e0c91b64aa2c0446ce", eligible: false },
      { _id: "64a6922ac91b64aa2c0446d1", eligible: false },
      { _id: "64a69240c91b64aa2c0446d2", eligible: true },
    ];
        await uploadAlbumSchema.updateMany(
      { _id: albumId, "sections._id": sectionId, "sections.sectionData.media._id": { $in: ids.map(obj => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(obj._id)) } },
      { $set: { "sections.$[outer].sectionData.media.$[inner].eligible": ids.map(obj => obj.eligible)  } },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "outer._id": sectionId }, { "inner._id": { $in: ids.map(obj => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(obj._id)) } }] }
    )
```

using this code its not working as expected its updating the eligible field as a array. so I need only to update the corresponding field with the respective value like this.

```
 {
    "_id": {
           "$oid": "64a691e0c91b64aa2c0446ce"
           },
    "image": "1.jpg",
    "eligible":false
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [`db.collection.bulkWrite()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) to update multiple documents with different documents.

> `bulkWrite()` takes an array of write operations and executes each of them.

E.g.(*"mongoose": "^7.3.1"*)

```
const albumId = '64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0f7';
const sectionId = '64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0f8';
const ids = [
  { _id: '64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0f9', eligible: false },
  { _id: '64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fa', eligible: false },
  { _id: '64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fb', eligible: true },
];
const r = await UploadAlbum.bulkWrite(
  ids.map((item) => {
    return {
      updateOne: {
        filter: {
          _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(albumId),
          'sections._id': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(sectionId),
        },
        update: { $set: { 'sections.$[].sectionData.media.$[m].eligible': item.eligible } },
        arrayFilters: [{ 'm._id': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item._id) }],
      },
    };
  }),
  { ordered: false },
);
console.log(r)
```

Debug logs:

```
BulkWriteResult {
  insertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 3,
  modifiedCount: 3,
  deletedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  upsertedIds: {},
  insertedIds: {}
}
```

Input documents:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0f7"),
    sections: [
      {
        sectionData: {
          media: [
            {
              image: '1.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0f9")
            },
            {
              image: '1.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fa")
            },
            {
              image: '1.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fb")
            },
            {
              image: '1.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fc")
            }
          ]
        },
        _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0f8")
      },
      {
        sectionData: {
          media: [
            {
              image: 'a.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fe")
            },
            {
              image: 'a.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0ff")
            },
            {
              image: 'a.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab100")
            },
            {
              image: 'a.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab101")
            }
          ]
        },
        _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fd")
      }
    ],
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Output documents:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0f7"),
    sections: [
      {
        sectionData: {
          media: [
            {
              image: '1.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0f9"),
              eligible: false
            },
            {
              image: '1.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fa"),
              eligible: false
            },
            {
              image: '1.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fb"),
              eligible: true
            },
            {
              image: '1.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fc")
            }
          ]
        },
        _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0f8")
      },
      {
        sectionData: {
          media: [
            {
              image: 'a.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fe")
            },
            {
              image: 'a.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0ff")
            },
            {
              image: 'a.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab100")
            },
            {
              image: 'a.jpg',
              _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab101")
            }
          ]
        },
        _id: ObjectId("64a78b1e1a6e122b5b3ab0fd")
      }
    ],
    __v: 0
  }
]
```